# Add csv data containing coordinates to a map generated from a shp file and obtain information on each point

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, r-sf

I am new to programming in SAS and I have been investigating to be able to join a shp file downloaded from the INE with a store characterization file that contains two fields with X and Y coordinates.

I would like to make a map for each autonomous community, so far fine, I have managed to make a join between the "base" map that I have downloaded from the INE with my characterization data by census section and this I have represented on a map, so you can see the map of the Basque Country region and in red, the polygons where there are shops.

This is almost what I want, but I don't want the entire polygon to be colored, I just want a point to appear in the polygon where the store is exactly (X and Y coordinates) and I would also like that at the point, at pass the cursor to me of the information contained in the store characterization csv or the file downloaded from the INE.

I don't know if I have explained myself well, I hope so, how could I do this? Thank you very much in advance, if you can help me in this I would be very happy.

You can download the INE file that contains all the polygons in Spain with all the census sections on this page: https://www.ine.es/ss/Satellite?L=es_ES&c=Page&cid=1259952026632&p=1259952026632&pagename=ProductosYServicios%2FPYSLayout
select the year 2021 and then go ahead.

I can't share the stores file, but it would work with any excel / csv that contains 2 fields, one with X coordinates and the other with Y coordinates.

https://ibb.co/26yqS8G
In this image you can see what I have done with the code below

I would like something similar but instead of coloring the polygons where there are stores, the exact points where the stores are located appear and that point gives me information (which comes from from csv)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
install.packages('rnaturalearth')
library(rnaturalearth)



ruta = "J:\\Data Quality & Process\\ABEL\\MAPAS\\CARACT_ESTANCOS_UV.csv"
datos.pos_ = read.csv2(ruta)
names(datos.pos_)


datos.INE = st_read('Espana_Seccionado2021/SECC_CE_20210101.shp')
names(datos.INE)

#Voy a intentar seccionar los datos del INE. País vasco (NCA)

PV = datos.INE[datos.INE$NCA == 'País Vasco' , ]

plot(st_geometry(PV), border="#aaaaaa", main="País Vasco")

#Join
datos_merged <- merge(PV, datos.pos_, by.x = "CUSEC", by.y = "SECCION_CENSAL")

plot(st_geometry(PV), border="#aaaaaa", main="País Vasco")
plot(st_geometry(datos.pos_), add=T, col="red")
plot(st_geometry(datos_merged_radio), add=T, lwd = 2) #Esto es para añadir un radio pero tengo que poner mas codigo antes que esta en el archivo de Pruebas20220111
´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some flavor of leaflet. You should learn a bit about [mapview](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/index.html).

Here this is a small example on Llanes (hoping it is also in Pais Vasco!).

The use of `osmdata` is just to get some shops around Llanes.

It should produce what you want. You can start with that then twink it with your data. good luck!

```
library(sf)
library(osmdata)
library(mapview)

#this will just download node for key = "shop" in Llanes
some_shop_in_Llanes <- osmdata::opq(osmdata::getbb("Llanes spain"),
                                   nodes_only = TRUE) %>% 
    osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "shop") %>% 
    osmdata::osmdata_sf() #keep them in sf format 
# some_shop_in_Llanes is a bit more complex object but our shopes are in 
# some_shop_in_Lanes$osm_points

# here I get their coords X/Y
just_the_coord <- sf::st_coordinates(some_shop_in_Llanes$osm_points) 

# I get plenty of data so I selected only the name and X?Y
shop_with_coords <- cbind(some_shop_in_Llanes$osm_points, just_the_coord) %>% 
                        dplyr::select(name, X, Y)
                
# then plot it! 
mapview(shop_with_coords)
```

Editing to provide just a data frame with X/Y

```
# 1. Some shops
shop <- data.frame(X = c(-4.758628, -4.758244, -4.756829, -4.759394, -4.753698,
                         -4.735330, -4.864548, -4.863816, -4.784694, -4.738924),
                   Y = c(43.42144, 43.42244, 43.42063, 43.42170, 43.41899,
                         43.41181, 43.42327, 43.42370, 43.42422, 43.40150),
                   name = LETTERS[1:10])

# 2. Convert into an sf object
shop_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(shop, coords = c("X", "Y"))

# 2.b editing to add CRS my bad!
shop_sf  <- sf::st_set_crs(shop_sf, 4326)

# Plot them thanks to mapview
mapview(shop_sf)
```

Comment: When I run all that, R closes, what do you mean by node? What does it mean? i dont understand nothing :(

Comment: A node is just a "point" In OpenStreet Map. I will edit with some coords around Llanes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your involvement and for helping me understand this better, I am very grateful, but when I run your code I get a gray screen: https://ibb.co/yWqMtDK, Can you tell me what is it due to?

Comment: https://ibb.co/r4XKNRn I want something like that but with the rows filled

Comment: @Abel On the second link you are sharing it look like you are using `sp` as "main" package. You should start using [sf](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/). I used `sp` a lot and `sf` will make your life easier (they are still some packages that require it but you can easily convert them see `sf::st_as_sf()`) . 

You should install all the packages that `mapview` needs first.  I think you should also have a working internet connection. You will have good insight here: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html?q=mapview#interactive-maps

Comment: I have a good internet connection but I don't know why the map appears in gray, I have installed mapview and sf but it appears in gray ... does it work for you?

Comment: @AbelPérez This is my bad! I have not provide shop a CRS! Just add `shop_sf  <- sf::st_set_crs(shop_sf, 4326)` and it should works ! (i will edit my answer)

Comment: The map keeps appearing in gray, could you tell me if with tmap can I add the points of sale? I have already achieved this: https://ibb.co/G5r6TG9 and now I want to add the points of sale here (they come from a csv with fields of lat and lon) if you help me with this I will love you very much

Comment: I want to add points that fall within those polygons, and these points are defined by the LAT and LON fields that I have in the stores csv file

Comment: Yes you can also use `tmap` (in interactive mode see https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap-book/nutshell.html#map-modes). " 
You need to convert your `datos.pos_` to an sf object (see the use of `st_as_sf`) and if the X/Y in your csv is not in EPSG 4326 you will need to transform it (see `sf::st_transform`). No need for that much love I hope it will works.

Comment: and once I have the data.pos_ transformed into sf and the coordinates in 4326, how can I join it? Thanks to that document that has passed me, I have managed to do everything, but I don't know how to make the union this without mapview, would you know how it would be done? If you answer me this I will leave you alone, you are a great sage. I have this: https://ibb.co/G5r6TG9 and this: https://ibb.co/8x8L9FX my goal is to merge these two maps, how could it be done? Could you make an example with code? you are so big, thank you very much for everything